# SharePoint 2010 FAST Search Crawl Rule Exclusions Are Case Sensitive

Tags: performance, search

We have SP2010 FAST search running and it works great.

I've had to set up some crawl rules to exclude certain sites/folders. Without checking the Match Case check box (making the crawl rule case-insensitive) it is still filtering results based on case. Has anybody else encountered this?

For example the crawl rule to exclude:

http://mysite.com/manuals/*/WebHelp/*

would return http://mysite.com/manuals/A/Webhelp/somepage.htm when it shouldn't since I'm not matching case.

I've done full crawls after adding the rules as well but it is still returning incorrect results.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you need add the rule with lowe case characters like "http://mysite.com/manuals/*/webhelp/*"

Additionally, SharePoint 2010's crawler normalizes all discovered links by converting them to lowercase

you can see description in: http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/sharepoint-2010-search---setting-up-the-crawler---using-crawl-rules.aspx